# Make a list of application name instead of package name

Tags: android

I have been able to get out a list using:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplications(0);
```

I then go through the list and and search for specific apps like (gmal, youtube, etc) and that works well.

However when I print the apps I want out it looks like this:

```
[ApplicationInfo{84a7553 com.google.android.youtube}...]
```

How can I get just the name of the app "youtube" instead?
Also if you know how to get the version of the app as well?

So basically I need to make a list of apps and their version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution :

```
public static String getApplicationName(Context context) {
    return String.valueOf(context.getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()));
}
```

In Activity :

```
String applicationName = getApplicationName(this);
```